# Adding a Dot Net 5 class library reference into SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

I am working on a **Dot Net 5 web application and have SSRS reporting in that project**. I have created a custom class library project (to add some business logics to display some values based on specific condition) in asp.net core 5 and added as reference into **SSRS report**.

**When I try to use the method from the referenced class library it is throwing error in the preview. If I remove the reference it works again.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**As a workaround, I have a added a new Dot Net Framework 4.7 Class Library project and added the class files from the .net 5 project to the Framework project as Link.** (By using  add -> existing item and add as link button).

Copied the library to the SSRS folder. ( In my system the path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS).

Not it worked. Cheers...